# NetBIOS Name 15 chars being cut off

Tags: windows, iis, netbios, msmq

I'm trying to debug some MSMQ related issues on a computer running Windows Server 2008 R2, which is not a member of a domain.  The computer's name (the one you see as 'Computer name' in Comtrol Panel -> System and Security -> System, I think that's the NetBIOS name?) is 16 characters long. And I've just noticed the name is truncasted to 15 characters in both IIS and MSMQ, which I guess is in line with MS restricting NetBIOS names to 15 characters.

In IIS, the root node is called X (X\) where X is the computer name with the final character removed.

Similarly if I look at the Message Queuing properties in server manager, (Server Manager -> Features -> Message Queuing -> Right-click to open properties window -> general tab) I see that the name of the computer has had the final character removed.

I'm curious to know if this computer name truncation is likely to cause any problems with IIS or MSMQ, or more generally? Would I be advised to get the computer renamed to something with just 15 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may likely have issues with MSMQ. Suggest you keep the computer hostname to 15 characters or less.